# Application of Python for loops for beginner

Tags: python, loops, export-to-csv

I am new to Python and struggling a bit with loops. I am trying to loop a series of tasks in a specific software. I have a dialog box that opens to imput the number of times I would like these tasks to loop. Within those tasks is a data export. I would like that to loop as well and add a number each time the loop runs. Example first loop Export_1, 2nd loop Export_2, 3rd loop, Export_3 and so on. Honestly I am not really sure where to begin. Here is my basic code with no looping.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import gom
import math


RESULT=gom.script.sys.execute_user_defined_dialog (content='<dialog>' \
' <title>Message</title>' \
' <style></style>' \
' <control id="OkCancel"/>' \
' <position>automatic</position>' \
' <embedding>always_toplevel</embedding>' \
' <sizemode>automatic</sizemode>' \
' <size width="238" height="176"/>' \
' <content rows="1" columns="2">' \
'  <widget row="0" column="0" rowspan="1" type="label" columnspan="1">' \
'   <name>label</name>' \
'   <tooltip></tooltip>' \
'   <text># OF LOOPS</text>' \
'   <word_wrap>false</word_wrap>' \
'  </widget>' \
'  <widget row="0" column="1" rowspan="1" type="input::string" columnspan="1">' \
'   <name>input</name>' \
'   <tooltip></tooltip>' \
'   <value></value>' \
'   <read_only>false</read_only>' \
'  </widget>' \
' </content>' \
'</dialog>')




gom.script.sys.recalculate_project (with_reports=False)

CAD_ALIGNMENT=gom.script.transform_element.by_rotation (
    Angle = 360/RESULT.input, 
    elements=[gom.app.project.inspection['TEST SECTION.Line profile'], gom.app.project.inspection['TEST SURFACE.Surface profile'], gom.app.project.inspection['TEST SECTION'], gom.app.project.actual_elements['TEST SECTION'], gom.app.project.inspection['TEST PT 003'], gom.app.project.inspection['TEST SURFACE'], gom.app.project.inspection['TEST PT 004'], gom.app.project.inspection['TEST PT 005'], gom.app.project.inspection['TEST PT 002'], gom.app.project.inspection['TEST PT 001'], gom.app.project.actual_elements['TEST SURFACE'], gom.app.project.actual_elements['TEST PT 001'], gom.app.project.actual_elements['TEST PT 005'], gom.app.project.actual_elements['TEST PT 002'], gom.app.project.actual_elements['TEST PT 004'], gom.app.project.actual_elements['TEST PT 003'], gom.app.project.inspection['TEST PT 001.dN'], gom.app.project.inspection['TEST PT 003.dN'], gom.app.project.inspection['TEST PT 002.dN'], gom.app.project.inspection['TEST PT 005.dN'], gom.app.project.inspection['TEST PT 004.dN']], 
    invert_transformation=False, 
    line=gom.app.system['system_line_x'])

gom.script.sys.recalculate_project (with_reports=False)

gom.script.view.set_tab_visible (
    view='table', 
    visible=True)

gom.script.table.export_table_contents (
    cell_separator=',', 
    codec='iso 8859-1', 
    decimal_separator='.', 
    elements=[gom.app.project.inspection['TEST SECTION.Line profile'], gom.app.project.inspection['TEST SURFACE.Surface profile'], gom.app.project.inspection['TEST PT 002.dN'], gom.app.project.inspection['TEST PT 005.dN'], gom.app.project.inspection['TEST PT 004.dN'], gom.app.project.inspection['TEST PT 006.dN'], gom.app.project.inspection['TEST PT 003.dN'], gom.app.project.inspection['TEST PT 001.dN']], 
    file='C:/Users/culp/Documents/Export_1.csv', 
    header_export=True, 
    line_feed='\n', 
    sort_column=0, 
    sort_order='ascending', 
    template_name='Details', 
    text_quoting='', 
    write_one_line_per_element=False)

gom.script.view.set_tab_visible (
    view='table', 
    visible=False)
```

I have tried doing the following

for i in range(1, number_of_times+1): and then substitute i into the file name being exported

however that just printed the numbers 1-whatever I entered. The rest of the processes happened and exported 1 data set. It did not loop and run again.

Comment: FYI, when you want to create a multi-line string, use triple quotes instead of all that escaping.

Comment: `for i in range(1, number_of_times+1):` and then substitute `i` into the file name being exported.

Comment: [The Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) gives some examples of for loops. The key thing is that anything you want looped needs to be inside the loop block, as those examples show. Anything after but not inside the loop isn't part of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

you can use for loops.

```
for i in range(5):
    print(i)
```

this code output would be

> 0
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
> 5